# Right side slider

Tags: jquery

Helo, Im trying to create slide to left when hover. The slide bar should be at right in browser like this

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.sideSlider = function(options) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var settings = $.extend({
            speed        : 1,
            side         : 'right',
            complete : null
        }, options);

        var side = 'marginRight';
        if(settings.side == 'right'){
            side = 'marginleft';
        }
        var speed_multiplier = parseInt(settings.speed);
        var finish = $this.css(side).replace('px','');
        var distance = $('.sideslider-close').width();
        var start =$('.sideslider').css(side).replace('px','');

        $this.mouseenter(function(){
            if($this.css(side).replace('px','')==start)
            {
                if(side == 'marginRight'){
                    $this.animate({marginRight:"+="+distance},speed_multiplier*1000,function(){finish=$this.css(side).replace('px','');});
                }
                else if(side == 'marginLeft')
                {
                    $this.animate({marginLeft:"+="+distance},speed_multiplier*1000,function(){finish=$this.css(side).replace('px','');});
                }


            }
        });
       $('.sideslider-tab, #sideslider .sideslider-close').click(function()
        {
            if($this.css(side).replace('px','')==finish)
            {
                if(side == 'marginRight'){
                    $this.animate({marginRight:"-="+distance},speed_multiplier*1000,function(){start=$this.css(side).replace('px','');});
                }
                else if(side == 'marginLeft')
                {
                    $this.animate({marginLeft:"-="+distance},speed_multiplier*1000,function(){start=$this.css(side).replace('px','');});
                }

            }
        });

        return $this.each( function() {

            if ( $.isFunction( settings.complete ) ) {
                settings.complete.call( this );
            }
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

```css
#sideslider {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    left: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 120px;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 3500;
    padding-right: 16px;
}

#sideslider .sideslider-tab {
    background-color: #222;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 36px;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    width: 144px;
    right: 295px;
}

#sideslider a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#sideslider-smartbutton {
    background-color: #222;
    margin-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 265px;
}

#sideslider .sideslider-close {
    background-color: #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 24px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 335px;
}


#sideslider-text .line {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#sideslider-text {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#sideslider-text .header {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
.sideclear {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 none;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sideslider side-filter" id="sideslider">
            <div class="sideslider-tab"> Filter </div>
            <div class="sideslider-close sideslider-close_en"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>Close&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color: #effbff; padding-top: 14px;">               
                
                <div class="streamline-height">
                     <form id="sidefilter"><div id="filter2"></div></form>              
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#sideslider').sideSlider();
                });                 
                </script>               
                <script>
                function move_filter() {
                  if ($(window).width() < 1200) {
                    $('#topfilter #filter1').contents().appendTo('#sidefilter #filter2')
                  } else {
                    $('#sidefilter #filter2').contents().appendTo('#topfilter #filter1')
                  }
                }
                $(document).ready(function() {
                  move_filter();
                });
                $(window).on('resize', move_filter);
                </script>
                
            </div>
            

        </div>
```

It will close to right when click close button. Trying to play around with negative margin and zero right, but its not responsive. Its turn out overflow-x when slide is moving. Or maybe have other sources that I can compare with.